# Is there a jQuery selector to accomplish this task?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-traversing

I have these 4 HTML snippets:

- #### Siblings:

  ```
  <div class="a">...</div>
  <div class="b">...</div>        <!--selected-->
  <div class="b">...</div>        <!--not selected-->
  ```
- #### Wrapped 1:

  ```
  <div class="a">...</div>
  <div>
      <div class="b">...</div>    <!--selected-->
  </div>
  <div class="b">...</div>        <!--not selected-->
  ```
- #### Wrapped 2:

  ```
  <div>
      <div class="a">...</div>
  </div>
  <div>
      <div class="b">...</div>    <!--selected-->
  </div>
  <div class="b">...</div>        <!--not selected-->
  ```
- #### Separated:

  ```
  <div class="a">...</div>
  <div>...</div>
  <div class="b">...</div>        <!--selected-->
  <div>...</div>
  <div class="b">...</div>        <!--not selected-->
  <div>...</div>
  <div class="b">...</div>        <!--not selected-->
  ```

How can I, with jQuery, select the next `.b` element for any given `.a` element, regardless of nesting?

I want something like this:

```
$('.a').each(function() {
    var nearestB = $(this)./*Something epically wonderful here*/;

    //do other stuff here
});
```

Comment: By chance is there a limit to how deeply nested the next b can be?

Comment: Probably, but I'd prefer a general solution.

Comment: Can you update your example to show the fact that there can be many .bs (not 1:1 with the .as)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here's a modified version of [Padel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141038/is-there-a-jquery-selector-to-accomplish-this-task/3141372#3141372)'s solution, that behaves *slightly* differently

```
var lastA = null;

$('.a, .b').each(function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('a'))
    {
        lastA = $(this);
    }
    else if(lastA)
    {
        doStuff(lastA,this); //doStuff(a,b)
        lastA = null;
    }
});
```

Comment: i like your own previous answer better, because it allows to be used on a per element basis, instead of only once on all elements.. i mean that it could be adapted to work on hover by finding the next `.b` element, while this one cannot be easily adapted to that scenario..

Answer (score 3):

Can you try this to see if it suits your case?

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var isA = false;

        $('div.a, div.b').each(function () {
            if ($(this).attr('class') == "a")
                isA = true;
            if ($(this).attr('class') == "b" && isA) {
                $(this).css("background", "yellow");
                isA = false;
            }
        });
    });
```

Regards...

Comment: Yes! That works. Although I think you may have just nudged me towards a better way.

Comment: It's a good thing then! Maybe work on it a little (change .attr('class') == "a" with .hasClass("a") etc) to make it better... Cheers!

Comment: Ok, I have a solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141038/is-there-a-jquery-selector-to-accomplish-this-task/3141476#3141476) that feels less like cheating (ie no changing variables). However, yours look much more efficient.

Answer (score 3):

Got it!

```
var both = $('.a, .b');

$('.a').each(function() {
    var nearestB = both.slice(both.index(this))
                       .filter('.b')
                       .first();

    //do stuff
});​
```

Comment: It is perfectly acceptable to mark your own answer as the accepted one: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/should-i-not-answer-my-own-questions

Comment: Indeed. However, I can't decide whether my answer is better than Padel's.

Answer (score 2):

How are you deciding which `.a` to select?  Is there a `.b` for ever `.a`?  Are you looping over each?  You could use the index of the `.a` and simply select the corresponding `.b`.

```
$(".a").each(function(){
    var index = $(".a").index(this);
    var theB = $(".b").get(index);
});
```

Comment: There _is_ a `.b` for every `.a`. There is _not_ an `.a` for every `.b`. So unfortunately that wouldn't work. All the `a.` s will be selected. See my updated question.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("div.a").nextAll("div.b")
```

Does this work?